# While I'm scraping with Selenium it keeps telling me that I'm an unusual browser and that I have to enable javascrept

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I just started learning programming and started with scraping with python Selenium but when get the Url and send elemets the website keep sending me (Your browser is a bit unusual...
Try disabling ad blockers and other extensions, enabling javascript, or using a different web browser.)
I tried some of the solutions provided on the site, but none of them solved my problem.
Can you explain and solve the problem with python please?

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.set_window_size(620, 720)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})






driver.get('https://sso.godaddy.com/v1/account/create?realm=idp&path=%2Fcontact%2Fvalidate%3FcontactType%3DphoneMobile%26app%3Dsso%26path%3Dprofile%252Fedit%26profileUpdate%3DTrue%26userInteraction%3DPROFILE_UPDATE&app=sso&auth_reason=1&iframe=false')
```

Comment: Change your User-Agent header to something sane. You can find your regular browser's UA by visiting http://whatsmyuseragent.org/

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://sso.godaddy.com/v1/login?regionsite=www&realm=idp&path=%2Fcontact%2Fvalidate%3FcontactType%3DphoneMobile%26app%3Dsso%26path%3Dprofile%252Fedit%26profileUpdate%3DTrue%26userInteraction%3DPROFILE_UPDATE&app=sso&auth_reason=1&iframe=false&marketid=en-US

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm inexperienced. So I'm having a hard time putting up the problem. The site link is above, you can search for it by selenium webdriver .and see the problem yourself when try to log in or sign up. Thanks a lot for trying to help sir. And I'm sorry again if I annoy  you